# Using a struct in a header file "unknown type" error

Tags: c, struct, header-files, kdevelop

I am using Kdevelop in Kubuntu.
I have declared a structure in my datasetup.h file:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

struct georeg_val {

    int p;
    double h;
    double hfov;
    double vfov;
};

#endif
```

Now when I use it in my main.c file

```
int main()
{
    georeg_val gval;

    read_data(gval); //this is in a .cpp file

}
```

I get the following error:

> georeg_chain.c:7:3: error: unknown type name 'georeg_val'

(This is in the `georeg_val gval;` line)

I would appreciate if anyone could help me resolve this error.

Comment: Are you mixing C and C++ together here?

Comment: Ensure you're importing the header: `import "datasetup.h"`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In C one has two possibilities to declare structure:

```
struct STRUCT_NAME {} ;
```

or

```
typedef struct {} STRUCT_ALIAS;
```

If you use first method (give struct a name) - you must define variable by marking it explicitly being `a struct`:

```
struct STRUCT_NAME myStruct;
```

However if you use second method (give struct an alias) then you can omit `struct` identifier - compiler can deduce type of variable given only it's `alias` :

```
STRUCT_ALIAS myStruct;
```

Bonus points:
You can declare struct with both it's name and alias:

```
typedef struct STRUCT_TAG {} STRUCT_TAG;
// here STRUCT_NAME == STRUCT_ALIAS
```

Then in variable definition you can use either first or second method. Why both of two worlds is good ? Struct alias lets you to make struct variable definitions shorter - which is a good thing sometimes. But struct name let's you to make `forward declarations`. Which is indispensable tool in some cases - consider you have circular references between structs:

```
struct A {
  struct B * b;
}
struct B {
  struct A * a;
}
```

Besides that this architecture may be flawed - this circular definition will compile when structs are declared in the first way (with names) AND struct pointers are referenced explicitly by marking them as `struct`.

Answer (score 8):

If you have to define a new type, you have to write:

```
typedef struct {

    int p;
    double h;
    double hfov;
    double vfov;
} georeg_val ;
```

Then you can use georeg_val as a new type.

Comment: Or switch to `struct georeg_val gval;` in `main`

Comment: @dead_jake Also `#include` the header file in main.c (if you haven't already done so)

Answer (score 4):

Defining a struct type (on this example, a binary search tree struct):

```
struct tree { 
  int info;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
} 

typedef struct tree treeNode;
```

Declaring a function eg.:

```
treeNode *insertElement(treeNode *treeA, int number);
```