# What does it mean when the name at the beginning of the struct and the one at the end of the struct are different?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What does it mean when the name at the beginning of the struct and the one at the end of the struct are different? For example:

```
struct book{
   char title[50];
   int year;
}boo;
```

or for example

```
typedef struct book{
    char title[50];
    int year;
}boo;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C : typedef struct name {...}; VS typedef struct{...} name;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720223/c-typedef-struct-name-vs-typedef-struct-name)

Comment: [struct name & alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385720/using-a-struct-in-a-header-file-unknown-type-error/10386888#10386888)

Comment: Why should they be same?

Comment: Ah I almost missed the [c] tag, generally you don't see the trailing alias in c++ because structs and classes are basically self aliasing and you do not use 'struct' before declarations. so you can just do `struct book{
   char title[50];
   int year;
} ;` followed by `book bookobj { "A lazy title", 1955 } ; `

Answer (score 3):

This example

```
struct book{
   char title[50];
   int year;
}boo;
```

Creates a variable called `boo` that has the type `struct book`.

The other example:

```
typedef struct book{
    char title[50];
    int year;
}boo;
```

Defines `boo` to be the same type as `struct book`, an alias sort-of.

Comment: Why do you say a `typedef` defines an “alias sort-of.” It defines an alias actually, not sort-of.

Comment: @EricPostpischil because English isn't my native language so it snuck in and added ambiguity I guess? I agree that it's an alias and that the "sort-of" can be left out.

Answer (score 3):

In the 1st case you define a struct and right away create a variable of its type.

```
struct book{
    char title[50];
    int year;
}boo; // <== boo is already a variable, you can start using it; boo.year = 2019;
```

In the second example you make a typedef saying that the 'boo' declaration is now the same as your struct so you can create variables using that 'boo' afterwards. In this case no variable is created at the time of the struct declaration.

```
typedef struct book{
    char title[50];
    int year;
}boo;

boo a, b; // <== here you create variables
```

Answer (score 3):

`struct book` is the *type name* (like `int` or `double`).  The type is being defined by the stuff between the curly braces - `{ char title[50]; int year; }`. In the first snippet, `boo` is being declared as an *object* (variable) of type `struct book`.

C allows you to both define the struct type and declare objects of that type in the same declaration.  It may make sense to see the two operations broken up:

```
struct book { char title[50]; int year; }; // creates the *type* "struct book"
struct book boo;                           // declares a *variable* of type "struct book"
```

The `typedef` facility allows you to create synonyms or aliases for a type - in this case, `typedef struct book { char title[50]; int year; } boo;` creates `boo` as a synonym for `struct book`.  You can then create objects as

```
boo b1; // b1 is type boo, which is a synonym for struct book.
```

Again, it may help to split things up:

```
struct book { char title[50]; int year; }; // creates the type "struct book"
typedef struct book boo;                   // makes boo an alias for type "struct book"
```

In `struct book`, `book` is the *tag name* for the struct type - it's what allows you to refer to that type after you've defined it, like

```
struct book b2;

void some_function( struct book b );
```

etc.

If you write something like

```
struct { char title[50]; int year; } boo;
```

then *only* `boo` can have that type - you can't declare other variables of that same type, because there's no way to refer to it anymore.  Even if you repeat the type:

```
 struct { char title[50]; int year; } boo;
 struct { char title[50]; int year; } b2;
```

`boo` and `b2` technically have different types, even though the type implementations are identical.

Now, if you use the typedef facility, you *can* omit the tag name:

```
typedef struct { char title[50]; int year } boo;
```

because now you refer to that type with the *`typedef` name* `boo`:

```
boo b2;

void some_function( boo b );
```

Answer (score 0):

When an identifier (a name) appears after `struct`, it is called a *tag* and the combined `struct` and identifier name a type. Quite simply, `struct book` is a type; its name is `struct book`.

When an identifier appears after the braces of a structure declaration, it is a separate name—it does not have an immediate connection with the structure. Its role depends on the larger declaration it is in. To see this, consider that one form of a declaration is “*type* *name* `;`”. For example, we can have:

```
int a;
char b;
struct foo c;
struct bar { float x, y, z; } d;
```

In each of these, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` is an identifier for an object being declared, and the text preceding it is a type name. `struct foo` and `struct bar { float x, y, z }` are merely type names that are complicated instead of being single words. When declaring an identifier, we can use any name we want (following the usual rules about which characters are used and about reserved names and such).

We can also have various modifiers before the type name, such as:

```
extern int a;
static char b;
const struct foo c;
typedef struct bar { float x, y, z; } d;
```

The first three above also declare objects. In the fourth, `typedef` is special. It says “This is not declaring an object; it is making a new name for a type.” The fourth declaration says “d” is a new name for `struct bar`.

It is common to use `typedef` to make an alias for a `struct` that has the same name as the structure tag, as in:

```
typedef struct bar { float x, y, z; } bar;
```

However, there is no requirement for this in C. The name of the structure and any aliases for its type are unrelated, unless a programmer writes a `typedef` making them the same. (In C++, this is done automatically; declaring a `struct bar` creates a type named `bar`. In C, structure tags are in a different name space than type names.)